# Можно ли так сократить предложение: «Продолжим на чём остановились»?

Tags: синтаксис

«Продолжим с того, на чём остановились.»
Можно ли сократить это предложение до следующего вида:
«Продолжим на чём остановились.».
Или это недопустимо даже для разговорной речи?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, в разговорной речи это и допустимо, но в порядке "*глотания*" слов, а *не* сокращения. Сокращением это может быть от "то, на чём остановились" или "на том, на чём остановились" - если какой-то предлог из "на чём" можно восстановить, то только имеющийся. Оба формально восстанавливаемых варианта не вполне естественны. В первом случае продолжают не повествование, а предмет ("то"), на котором произошла остановка, во втором - "продолжают на том, на чём остановились" (смысл с другим предлогом меняется: нет движения в повествовании, оно как бы не обещается дальше предмета, на котором остановились, в отличие от "с того").

Answer (score 2):

**Продолжим (разговор) с того, на чём остановились.**

**Указательное слово необходимо даже  в разговорной речи.** Это СПП с придаточным местоименно-определительным, наличие определяемого местоимения обязательно.

Оно и так уже разговорное, так как в нем  пропущено прямое дополнение.